# Different outputs with tinymce setcontent, appliying raw format or default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, format, tinymce

why do we have different outputs with the following examples on tinymce?

```
var foo = '<html><head></head><body><p></p>xxxxx';

// generates some empty lines and the content
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(foo);

// the content starts from the top, without any lines
tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(foo, {format : 'raw'});

// generates the same (without any empty line, like raw format)
$(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).html(foo);
```

you may see a working example on http://jsfiddle.net/ht1dpcdu/